# How to access a constant in an Angular 2 component and service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a constants file **constants.ts**:

```
export const C0NST = "constant";
```

I access it in a service **some.service.ts** like so:

```
import { C0NST } from './constants';

console.log(C0NST); // "constant"
```

However, when I access it in a component template:

**some.component.ts**:

```
import { C0NST } from './constants';
```

**some.component.html**:

```
{{ C0NST }} <!-- Outputs nothing -->
```

However defining a member in the component class works:

**some.component.ts**

```
public const constant = C0NST;
```

**some.component.html**

```
{{ constant }} <!-- constant -->
```

I don't understand why I was able to access the imported constant directly in the service class but not in the component template even though I imported it in the component class.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In Angular2, the template can only access fields and methods of the component class. Everything else is off-limits. This includes things which are visible to the component class.

The way to go around this is to have a field inside the component, which just references the constant, and use that instead.

---

It's one limitation of the design, but perhaps you should think a bit more about why you need a constant in the template in the first place. Usually these things are used by components themselves, or services, but not the template.

Comment: Thanks Horia. I have a list of GIF URLs that I need to source from Giphy so I'm saving the URLs in the constants file. I intend to use these throughout the application across components. What is a better way according to you?

Comment: @KabirRoy That sounds like a decent thing to do actually. If you have a relatively small number of images, you could actually create components for them, and use the giphy URL directly in the source (like you'd be doing for an asset provided by your application). But this sounds like a good approach, regardless.

Comment: how about formating strings "mm/dd/yyyy" they are trasversal to the whole application, why it should not be accessible in any template ?

Answer (score 88):

Since in the Component's template you can only use attributes of the Component's class, you can't directly use any external constants (or external variables).

The most elegant way that I've found so far is the following:

```
import { MY_CONSTANT } from '../constants';

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class MyTestComponent implements OnInit {

  readonly MY_CONSTANT = MY_CONSTANT;

  // ...
}
```

which basically just creates a new attribute `MY_CONSTANT` inside the component class. Using [readonly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier) we make sure that the new attribute cannot be modified.

Doing so, in your template you can now use:

```
{{ MY_CONSTANT }}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer but you should add `static` to avoid reassignment in constructor. So it really should be: `readonly myConstant = MY_CONSTANT;`
Please also note style guide recommendations for constant syntax.

Answer (score 23):

There are two best directions in my opinion:

### Wrapping constants as internal component property

**enum.ts**

```
export enum stateEnum {
  'DOING' = 0,
  'DONE',
  'FAILED'
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { stateEnum  } from './enum'
export class EnumUserClass {
  readonly stateEnum : typeof stateEnum = stateEnum ;    
}
```

Example uses enum, but this can be any type of defined constant. `typeof` operator gives you all of benefits of TypeScript typing features. You can use then this variable directly in templates:

**component.html**

```
<p>{{stateEnum.DOING}}<p>
```

This solution is less efficient in memory usage context, because you are basically duplicating data (or references to constants) in each component you wish to use it. Beside that, syntax
`readonly constData: typeof constData = constData`
in my opinion introduce a lot of syntax noise and may be confusing to newcommers

### Wrapping external constant in component function

Second option is to wrap your external variable/constant with component function and use that function on template:

**enum.ts**

```
export enum stateEnum {
  'DOING' = 0,
  'DONE',
  'FAILED'
}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { stateEnum  } from './enum'
export class EnumUserClass {
  getEnumString(idx) {
    return stateEnum[stateEnum[idx]];
  }   
}
```

**component.html**

```
<p>{{getEnumString(1)}}</p>
```

Good thing is that data is not duplicated in controller but other major downside occur. According to Angular team, usage of functions in templates is not recommended due to change detection mechanism, which works way less efficient in case of functions returning values to templates: change detection have no idea does value return by a function has changed, so it will be called way often than needed (and assuming you returning `const` from it, it's actually needed only once, when populating template view. It may be just a bit efficiency killing to your application (if you are lucky) or it may totally break it down if function resolves with `Observable` for instance, and you use `async` pipe to subscribe to results. You can refer to my short article on that [HERE](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-change-your-angular-app-ram-eating-beast-tomasz-budzi%C5%84ski/?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base_post_details%3B0YIDka6LQ2GorUCOSW3OVA%3D%3D)

Answer (score 22):

The scope of Angular2 template bindings is the component instance. Only what's accessible there can be used in bindings.

You can make it available like

```
class MyComponent {
  myConst = CONST;
}
```

```
{{myConst}}
```

Comment: Any downsides to this ? I am thinking that if I CONST is a enum and change detection is Push there should be none.

Comment: @bhantol I don't think there are downsides.

Comment: This is not a constant. `myConst` can be reassigned.

Comment: @mrgoos `CONST` is constant. You can't access const values directly in Angular bindings (at least not at the time when I posted this answer - not up-to-date with Angular development)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer- it is constant but `myConst` **is not**.
It can be modified in `MyComponent` class.

Comment: I know that, but this way you can render the value of the constant. You can also use a getter if it bothers you that the value can be modified.

Comment: Yes, it should bother since the final result is that it's not a real const.
There IS a way to use a real const and it's mentioned by @Shin below.

Comment: How can we use pipe as a index of the array, any idea?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a BaseComponent , it is a place where you should create your constant instances and then you can create your FooComponent extends BaseComponent and you can use your constants.