# Constant in Angular2 template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am looking for a more elegant solution for using constants in Angular2 templates. Here is my current solution:

**constants.module.ts**

```
export const DISPLAY_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/dd/yyyy';
```

**some.component.ts**

```
import {DISPLAY_DATE_FORMAT} from "constants.module";

export class SomeComponent {

readonly DISPLAY_DATE_FORMAT = DISPLAY_DATE_FORMAT;
.
.
.
```

**some.component.html**

```
<p>{{myDate| date : DISPLAY_DATE_FORMAT}}</p>
```

I do not like that I have to redeclare DISPLAY_DATE_FORMAT in some.component.ts.

Comment: You can only access properties from a template, so there is no alternative to what you are doing.

Comment: If you have to use use this in most of your components and if you are using routing then create one class that has declarations and extend it from your base routing class, so no need to declare in all component.Just extend one class which has declaration and call super constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a constant in an Angular 2 component and service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237561/how-to-access-a-constant-in-an-angular-2-component-and-service)