# angular2 how to access class constants in html

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some constants defined as public static readonly in a typescript class. This contains some general constants which is across the application.
How to access them in component html? 
is there a way directly to use in html? 
will something like {{MyConstantsFactory.Myconstant} work?

Comment: Please add some code where you define `MyConstantsFactory`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a constant in an Angular 2 component and service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237561/how-to-access-a-constant-in-an-angular-2-component-and-service)

Answer (score 4):

No, you have to cast them locally (using your factory) in the class's constructor and use them as you would normally use any property

Answer (score 3):

If you add a global variable to your component you can access it like this:

```
@Component({
    template: `<div>MyConstant is {{ myConstanstsFactory.MyConstant }}</div>`
})

class MyComponent {
   public myConstanstsFactory = MyConstantsFactory;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not access static fields from HTML, but you could define a getter to access them:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public static readonly CONFIG = { a: 1, b: 2 };

  get config() {
    return AppComponent.CONFIG;
  }

}

// in HTML
<div>{{ config | json }}</div>
```