# html registers environmental variables as undefined

Tags: html, angular, environment-variables

I have an Angular project with the following environmental variable file

canvases.ts

```
export const Canvases = {
    bmc: [
        ['KP', 'Key Partners'],
        ['KA', 'Key Activities'],
        ['KR', 'Key Resources'],
        ['VP', 'Value Propositions'],
        ['CR', 'Customer Relationships'],
        ['CH', 'Channels'],
        ['CS', 'Customer Segments'],
        ['Cost', 'Cost Structure'],
        ['Rev', 'Revenue Streams']
    ],
    gpr: [
        ['Gain', 'Gain'],
        ['Pain', 'Pain'],
        ['Inertia', 'Inertia']
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to display data from this file by calling the variable directly from the html file

.ts file

```
import {Canvases} from '../../../../environments/canvases'
```

.html file

```
<app-canvas-section [Name]="Canvases.bmc[0]"></app-canvas-section>
```

However the console keeps complaining that I'm trying to access property 'bmc' of undefined, why is that so? Can I not access environmental variables directly from my html file?

**EDIT:** After experimenting a little, I managed to fix the problem by doing the following

.ts file

```
import {Canvases} from '../../../../environments/canvases'
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
Canvases=Canvases;
}
```

.html file

```
<app-canvas-section [Name]="this.Canvases.bmc[0]"></app-canvas-section>
```

Although it seems a little hacky and I still don't understand what was wrong with the original code. Can anyone explain?

Comment: try to write in your html template `{{ Canvases  | json }}` and see what variable has

Comment: compiler.js:2420 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{Canvases | json}}.bmc[0]]

Comment: `this` is not required in `[Name]="Canvases.bmc[0]"`. the reason it works like this is because template can only refer to the component class fields and a few js builtin literals.

Comment: In Angular2, the template can only access fields and methods of the component class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237561/how-to-access-a-constant-in-an-angular-2-component-and-service

Comment: thanks @ritaj , you can post as answer and i will accept