# How to inject a parameter from one service to another service in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have the following wrapper service around a third party storage library. It accepts a config parameter which can be different based on the storage table we want to use:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {
    store: Storage;

    constructor(storeConfig: StorageConfig) {
        this.store = new Storage(storeConfig);
    }

    keys(): Promise<any[]> {
        return this.store.keys();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, I want to use that service in another service

```
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        public store: LocalStorageService,
        private router: Router,
    ) { }
    ...
}
```

What's the best way to pass something like AuthStorageConfig as a parameter to LocalStorageService from my AuthService?

```
export const AuthStorageConfig = {
    ...DefaultStorageConfig,
    storeName: 'auth',
} as StorageConfig;

export const SyncStorageConfig = {
    ...DefaultStorageConfig,
    storeName: 'sync',
} as StorageConfig;
```

I've gotten around this by using a useFactory method for the time being, but I've had trouble trying to mock the LocalStorageService dependency in tests, so I would rather not use the useFactory method unless I'm missing something and need to use it.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
    useFactory: (router: Router) => new AuthService(
        new LocalStorageService(AuthStorageConfig),
        router
    ),
    deps: [Router]
})
export class AuthService {
   constructor(
            public store: LocalStorageService,
            private router: Router,
        ) { }
...
```

Comment: There is a similar question but with components, maybe it helps..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237561/how-to-access-a-constant-in-an-angular-2-component-and-service

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that helps. I can access the constant, but I'm trying to determine how to inject it using dependency injection instead of passing it like I'm doing in the useFactory method.

Comment: Not sure what is that you are trying to accomplish by injecting the constant instead of importing it , like the answer from Francesco Borzi(inside the link I provided)

Comment: If I get rid of the useFactory method, then how will the dependency injection know how to pass the AuthStorageConfig into the LocalStorageService constructor? That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do. In the AuthService, the 'public store: LocalStorageService' is in the constructor. So as part of the DI, it's going to try to construct a LocalStorageService, but it doesn't have a config to pass.

Comment: I get it now, sorry I can not help with that

Comment: Use `InjectionToken` together with the `@Inject()` constructor parameter decorator factory, to make this configuration object a properly injected dependency.