# Angular html refer to Class name defined in ts

Tags: angular

In Angular ts files, I define some Classes with static data fields.

```
export class MyClass {
  static readonly Value1 = 'Value 1'; 
  static readonly Value2 = 'Value 2';
}
```

Is there a way in HTML to user these static members directly?

```
<div *ngIf="chosenValue === MyClass.Value1"> ...... </div>
<div *ngIf="chosenValue === MyClass.Value2"> ...... </div>
```

Comment: You could add a property of MyClass in your component file, and validate your condition with that property.

Comment: component template can only access component attributes. nothing else. this is by design. similar question: [How to access a constant in an Angular 2 component and service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237561/how-to-access-a-constant-in-an-angular-2-component-and-service)