# Cannot read property 'ACCEPTED' of undefined at Component

Tags: angular, typescript

i declared a const

```
export class FriendRequest {
  constructor(){
  }
}

export const  FRIEND_REQUEST_STATUSES = {
  ACCEPTED : "acc",
  WAITING :"wait",
  DECLINED : "dec"   
};
```

i imported and called this const in a component

component.ts

```
import { FriendRequest,FRIEND_REQUEST_STATUSES} from './../../models/friend-request';
```

component.html

```
 <ion-button (click)='updateFriendRequestStatus(friendRequest.id,FRIEND_REQUEST_STATUSES.ACCEPTED)'>
```

error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ACCEPTED' of undefined
> at FriendRequestsModalComponent_ion_item_10_Template_ion_button_click_7_listener

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237561/how-to-access-a-constant-in-an-angular-2-component-and-service

Comment: @R.Richards i tried exactly the same solution it dosen't work

Comment: Then show that code in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular, templates can only access properties/methods present on component instance.  Since your enum is not present on component instance, you are getting this error.

In order for this to work, you need to set the enum as one of the properties of the component class.

in your component where you have imported this enum, define a variable like this

```
public readonly FRIEND_STATUS = FRIEND_REQUEST_STATUSES;
```

Now, in your template you can access this enum via **FRIEND_STATUS** like this:

```
 <ion-button (click)='updateFriendRequestStatus(friendRequest.id,FRIEND_STATUS.ACCEPTED)'>
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer @Ritesh there is no other way where i can access the const in HTML without declaring another variable ?

Comment: @yassinegharsallah in Angular template can only access properties/methods available in component instance (this). You can't access const variables defined in component in templates.